# [[object Object]] in input text angularjs

Tags: angularjs, object, input, angularjs-ng-model, object-object-mapping

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="addCreditoBuscar" id="addCreditoBuscar" ng-controller="AddCreditoAppController">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Buscar</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buscar" ng-model="addCreditoBuscar.buscar" ng-required="true" placeholder="Buscar por cedula, nombre o apellido">
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="addCreditoBuscar.buscar.$error.required">Este campo es requerido es requerido.</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my code for a input text, but the result is this one - http://prntscr.com/73otmc

Comment: You are getting this as `addCreditoBuscar.buscar` is an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: put this beside input and see exactly what object looks like in the view `<pre>{{addCreditoBuscar.buscar | json}}</pre>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple. You are using the same "form name" than the object you want to put. Change the "Form name" to one different like name="formAddCreditoBuscar"

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="formAddCreditoBuscar" id="addCreditoBuscar" ng-controller="AddCreditoAppController">
```

Then your problem would disappear

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: Ahh, had this due to silly copy-paste errors. Adapted the `[ngModel]` linking, but forgot the name.

Answer (score 1):

**Your input element is coercing the value you provided to a string.** Your value is an object, so it is coercing it to the string value of that object (`[[object Object]]`).

**To fix this, you need to access a *property* of that object.**

`ng-model="addCreditoBuscar.buscar"` is an object, therefore it will show up as `[[object Object]]`, as something like `Object.prototype.toString()` is acting on the object in order to coerce it to a string value in your `input` element.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    someProp: 'someVal'
};

console.log(''+a); // => "[object Object]"
```

The above demonstrates string coercion from an object.

If you would like to show a property from that object, simply use the object attribute accessor (the dot `.`):

```
addCreditoBuscar.buscar.whateverProperty
```

Therefore, whenever your `input` element coerces the property to a value, if the value is a string, it will show up as a string (which is your intended output):

```
console.log(''+a.someProp); // => "someVal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could erase the displayed value by explicitly change the HTMLElement.value property at every change of your model value. You can create a directive to handle that.

```
app.directive('labelField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    element[0].value = newValue[attrs['labelField']];
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

use it by passing the field to display in the directive

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myobject" label-field="myfield">
```

E.g. to store in `$scope.user` an object like `{name:"John","email":"a@a.a"}`, you would use it like that :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user" label-field="name">
```